# android: crash when loading a layout with changed text

Tags: java, android, string, out-of-memory, allocation

I've a layout with lines that each line contains images and text of 5 characters. When I load this layout about 50-100 successive times, the app crashes. -I just start the activity of this layout, press back and start it again with different parameters and so on..

**I load the same layout BUT each of the 50-100 times has different images and text that are set within the onCreate code**

The compiler succeeds to reach to the end of the onCreate code.

What's the problem with the allocation?

Why did the allocation fail?

Can I know who's the problematic string?

And how do I solve it?

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.sampleapp, PID: 24414                              
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 566582 byte allocation with 326088 free bytes and 318KB until OOM
at java.lang.StringFactory.newStringFromChars(Native Method)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.toString(AbstractStringBuilder.java:629)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(StringBuilder.java:663)
at org.chromium.content_public.browser.LoadUrlParams.buildDataUri(LoadUrlParams.java:113)
at org.chromium.content_public.browser.LoadUrlParams.createLoadDataParamsWithBaseUrl(LoadUrlParams.java:164)
at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.loadDataWithBaseURL(AwContents.java:1460)
at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.loadDataWithBaseURL(WebViewChromium.java:609)
at android.webkit.WebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(WebView.java:978)
at com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.h.a(Unknown Source)
at com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.h.loadBannerAd(Unknown Source)
at com.facebook.ads.internal.DisplayAdController.a(Unknown Source)
at com.facebook.ads.internal.DisplayAdController.o(Unknown Source)
at com.facebook.ads.internal.DisplayAdController.d(Unknown Source)
at com.facebook.ads.internal.DisplayAdController$5.run(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: `at com.facebook.ads`... Facebook is the problem

Comment: you are so right! Without the loadAd, the app doesn't crash even after 100 times! and then I tried to use try-catch but it couldn't catch the exception. anyway thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems to have a memory leak either because your app is not handling the fb library correctly or it might be an issue with fb lib..You need to analyse your app using

https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-memory.html

> Android Monitor provides a Memory Monitor so you can more easily
>   monitor app performance and memory usage to find deallocated objects,
>   locate memory leaks, and track the amount of memory the connected
>   device is using. The Memory Monitor reports how your app allocates
>   memory and helps you to visualize the memory your app uses. It lets
>   you: